# How to do UDP Broadcast in ARC Welder?

Tags: udp, automatic-ref-counting, broadcast

My Android app does an UDP Broadcast to allow other devices to discover the service on the network. It works well on real devices (phones and tablets).

However, when I run my app in ARC Welder on PC, the UDP Broadcast doesn't work. The other devices on the network cannot receive the broadcast.

Is it possible to do UDP Broadcast in ARC Welder?
If it's possible, how to configure it?

Thanks,
Cow.

Answer (score 0):

It's firewall issue. Once I've turned off my firewall, it works.